# Bot Framework: Persistent storage best practise

Tags: c#, botframework, persistent-storage

I'm looking for some guidance for the best approach to Bot persistent storage. With the Bot Framework, the 2 approaches I've seen to storing data is in memory and persistent (Cosmos db/Azure blob).

In my Bot currently I have some data that I'm storing in accessors (it's the matched intent) that I just want for the lifetime of the the conversation, I have no need for it to be persisted past the current conversation.

Looking at the Microsoft articles on [persistent storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-persist-user-inputs?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp), the recommended approach is to store everything in persistent storage as in memory is volatile.

How have other people approached storage for Production Bots? Are you storing everything in persistent storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Persistent` storage is... persistent. `InMemory` isn't and should not be used, except for locally running bot while debugging.

You must store values that are needed for a conversation in persistent storage, in order to be able to continue your conversation in 10 seconds, 10 minutes, 10 hours...

If you are really concerned by the duration of storage of these items, ensure that you clean them when you don't need them anymore in your code

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas R for confirming, that is a good point about the clearing down when finished with the data.